# React native and react-navigation returning typeerror:null is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I dont know what is wrong with this react native app that am creating that is returning the above error and I can't really say this is what is wrong with the code but I have a feeling the error is coming from react-navigation. What I want to do is check if the numbers of feed is greater than zero(0) and if it is, display the content(s) and if not display NO Saved Feed.

This is the error am having

> React native returning typeerror:null is not an object(evaluating feeds.length)
>
> React-native version: latest version
>
> React version: latest version
>
> React-navigation version: 2.0.1

And this is the code

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native'

import CenterMessage from '../components/CenterMessage'

import { colors } from '../theme'

export default class Feeds extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Feeds',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: '400'
    }
  }
  navigate = (item) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Feed', { feed: item })
  }
  render() {
    const { screenProps: { feeds } } = this.props
    return (
      <ScrollView  contentContainerStyle={[!feeds.length && { flex: 1 }]}>// error here !feeds.length
        <View style={[!feeds.length && { justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1 }]}>// error here !feeds.length
          {
            !feeds.length && <CenterMessage message='No saved feeds!' />// error here !feeds.length
          }
          {
            feeds.map((item, index) => (
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.navigate(item)} key={index} >
                <View style={styles.feedContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.feed}>{item.feed}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.country}>{item.country}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            ))
          }
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  feedContainer: {
    padding: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: colors.primary
  },
  feed: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  country: {
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)'
  },  
})
```

and this is the app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import Tabs from "./src";

const key = "state";

const initialState = [{
  feed: 'Alcohol kills some students sometimes ago',
  title: 'Alcohol',
  id: 0,
  replies: []
},
{
  feed: 'Tokyo',
  title: 'Cigarette',
  id: 1,
  replies: []
}]
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    feeds: []
  };
  
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      let feeds = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      feeds = JSON.parse(feeds);
      this.setState({ feeds });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error from AsyncStorage: ", e);
    }
  }

  addFeed = (feed) => {
    const feeds = this.state.feeds;
    feeds.push(feed);
    this.setState({ feeds });
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(feeds))
      .then(() => console.log("storage updated!"))
      .catch(e => console.log("e: ", e));
  };

  addReply = (Reply, feed) => {
    const index = this.state.feeds.findIndex(item => {
      return item.id === feed.id;
    });
    const chosenFeed = this.state.feeds[index];
    chosenFeed.replies.push(Reply);
    const feeds = [
      ...this.state.feeds.slice(0, index),
      chosenFeed,
      ...this.state.feeds.slice(index + 1)
    ];
    this.setState(
      {
        feeds
      },
      () => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(feeds))
          .then(() => console.log("storage updated!"))
          .catch(e => console.log("e: ", e));
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs
        screenProps={{
          feeds: this.state.feeds,
          addFeed: this.addFeed,
          addReply: this.addReply
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[image: image 1]
[image: image error 2]
[image: Image error 3]

Is it that the library are not properly link or configure?

Comment: Could you console log ```this.props.screenProps```? What will it display?

Comment: @MaksymBezruchko where would i do the console as am using android emulator

Comment: Do you use React Native Debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `this.props.screenProps.feeds` parameter is null. Check if you passed the `feeds` parameter to your component correctly